# How to access files outside of the container while I've run to the container bash?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose which contains two containers. Each container includes `volumes:` sections. I see the `volumes:` is created on the file system once the docker-compose is run.

Sometimes I run into the docker to do admin tasks by this command:

```
sudo docker exec -it MongoDb bash
```

When I am in the bash of the container, I need to access files outside of the container. For example to restore a database file, etc.

My question is how to access those files outside of the container while I've run to the container bash?

Comment: A container cannot access files from the host unless they are explicitly exposed at runtime as a bind mount (`docker run -v /host/path:/container/path ...`).

Comment: @larsks my be I have not described my question well. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `volumes` part of the `docker-compose` shows a pair like:

```
- ./mongo-data:/mongodata
```

The first part of it is in outside of the container. Whatever exists there, can be access in the container in a directory names as second part.

In this case, I can copy a file to the `mongo-data` directory in the host, and in inside the container, in the bash, I can access it in a directory named `mongodata`